# Return ActionResponseBuilder from function when called from mobile Gmail Compose

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I recently started to receive some reports from users that this stopped working recently, but only on mobile.  I've been able to reproduce it with the demo cat application by changing the onGmailInsertCat to

```
function onGmailInsertCat(e) {
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
        .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
            .setText("notificationText")
            .setType(CardService.NotificationType.INFO))
        .build();      // Don't forget to build the response!
}
```

On desktop this shows a notification but on mobile nothing happens.  I've seen similar results when I return a new card instead.  Is there still a way to return a new card on mobile/iOS gmail?

Comment: Do you get a console error? You may need to inspect your device on desktop to check

Comment: Thanks, I'm not getting any error logged.  The problem only happens in the iOS Gmail App.  I think that we get the same error with the demo cat app on mobile as well.